# Discontinuous convolutions

Tags: measure-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, fourier-analysis

Is the following true?

The convolution of two infinitely differentiable as well as integrable real functions can be nowhere continuous.

A reference/proof idea would be very helpful.

Comment: First of all, if you are considering the convolution of two *non-integrable* functions, how are you defining this?

Comment: The functions have to be in $L^1[\mathbf{R}]$

Comment: "can be nowhere continuous." I'm confused; are you asking for an examples of two smooth, integrable functions that have a continuous convolution? Because Nate gives an example. Sure you don't mean "nowhere *continuous*"?

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant nowhere continuous.

Comment: If the derivatives are integrable, the convolution will also be differentiable.  So the derivatives would have to behave rather badly at infinity...

Comment: Further to Nate's comment, it seems that it is precisely the bad behaviour at infinity which we either need to control (to prove no such pairs of functions exist) or to "exaggerate" (to give an example of two such functions). It may also be worth observing - apologies if this is known to everyone reading - that the convolution of two integrable and *square*-integrable functions is continuous and bounded on ${\mathbb R}$ (in fact it lies in $C_0({\mathbb R})$).

Comment: It might help if the original poster added a little more on what kind of examples he or she has already tried. One natural idea, if one is thinking of smooth, integrable but *non-square-integrable* functions, is to take a smooth compactly supported bump function, consider dilations of it to obtain bump functions which have small support and large height, and then stack together (translates of?) these bumps. But I haven't gone through actual calculations to determine what the convolution square of such an example would look like.

Comment: As a warmup, do you know an example where a convolution of integrable smooth functions is discontinuous even at *one* point?

Comment: Don't know how to do the warmup, but here is a possibly silly suggestion. First, identify an $L_1$ smooth function $f$ and a sequence of real numbers $x_1, \dots \rightarrow \infty$ such that the function $\sum_i f(x - x_i)$ is discontinuous. Then $f \star g$ is discontinuous if $g(x) = \sum_i \delta(x - x_i)$. Now try replacing $g$ by a smooth approximation.

Comment: Here's a sort of example I don't want: Let f_n  be a smooth approximation to n times the characteristic function of [n, n + (1/n)^3]. Let f be the sum of f_n's where n runs over all positive integers. Let g be an even function which matches f on positive numbers. Then g is an infinitely differentiable L1 function whose convolution with itself at 0 is infinite and therefore discontinuous at 0. But this is not something I want. I want (f * g) to be finite everywhere and continuous nowhere and I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 6):

I believe the answer is yes. though I don't quite have a precise construction.  The basic idea is to find a series $f = \sum_n f_n$ of increasingly narrow bump functions $f_n$ whose $L^1$ norms decay very quickly (e.g. exponentially fast in $n$), but such that the series converges to a nowhere continuous function $f$; I think some sort of "typewriter function" construction will do this.  If the bump functions $f_n$ are reasonable, then they should be expressible as (or modifiable to) a convolution $f_n = g_n * h_n$, where the $g_n$ are also narrow (but perhaps tall) bump functions whose $L^1$ norms also decay very quickly.  If one then sets $g(x) := \sum_n g_n(x-x_n)$ and $h(x) := \sum_n h_n(x+x_n)$ where $x_n$ goes to infinity extremely quickly with $n$ (e.g. $x_n = 2^{2^n}$) then I think $g*h$ should differ from $f$ by a continuous function and thus also be nowhere continuous, despite $g, h$ being infinitely smooth and integrable.

Comment: If $f_n$ is a sequence of continuous functions whose sum converges pointwise to $f$ then isn't it true that the set of points of continuity of f is dense in reals?

Comment: Well, one only needs the series here to converge almost everywhere, rather than pointwise, so I think we can escape the Baire class.  The construction I had in mind had the f_n being concentrated near multiples of 1, then multiples of 1/2 (perhaps with the opposite sign to keep the partial sums bounded), then multiples of 1/4, and so forth, while becoming very rapidly narrower as one progresses, which should create a lot of oscillation at every scale, while still being absolutely summable in L^1 and thus convergent pointwise a.e.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we get the stronger statement that the convolution of an infinitely differentiable integrable function $f$ with any integrable function $g$ will result in $f*g$ being infinitely differentiable. In fact, $(f*g)' = f'*g$ (This can be found in The Fourier Transform and Its Applications, Bracewell) Thus the convolution of two infinitely differentiable, integrable functions will necessarily be (infinitely) differentiable and so also continuous.

<strike>EDIT: Also, if my math is correct, we can check this formula via the Fourier transform:</strike>

$\widehat{((f*g)')}(r) = ir\widehat{f*g}(r) = ir\widehat{f}(r)\widehat{g}(r) = \widehat{f'}(r)\widehat{g}(r) = \widehat{(f'*g)}(r)$

Apologies, this only applies in the case that $f$ is compactly supported. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: What if f' is not integrable?

Comment: Please double-check the hypotheses of the theorems you're using.  The proofs I'm familiar with require $f'$ to be integrable, which is not assumed here.

Comment: I think this problem is more subtle than it looks, and this answer is incorrect as written (without a lot of extra explanation). For example, I'm fairly sure that $f'$ need not  make sense as a tempered distribution in general, so how can you take the Fourier transform? $f'$ can be very badly behaved!

Comment: Also, the space of Fourier transforms of continuous $L^1$ functions (as well as the Fourier transforms of $L^1$ itself) doesn't have any nice characterisation as far as I know, so even if we could take the Fourier transform, it wouldn't necessarily be able to help us...consider $e^{-x^2} sin(\exp(\exp(\exp(x))))$, which is $C^\infty$ and $L^1$, but with ***very*** nasty derivatives!!

Comment: My mistake, you are right - I have been working with $\mathbb{T}$ for so long I forgot I require $f$ to be compactly supported.